# Enforce two factor authentication in google compute engine projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use google compute engine in an organisation of ~100 people. How do I make sure that all the accounts I add to a compute engine project have two factor auth enabled?

I searched google documentation for `(enforce|ensure|mandatory) two factor (gcloud|gce|google cloud)` but didn't find anything that answered my question.

This question is only partially answered. It is possible with Gsuite. It remains unknown if this can be done without Gsuite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new service called [Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7319251).

> Cloud Identity provides free, managed Google Accounts to users who don’t need G Suite Services, such as Gmail or Drive.

Relevant for you:

> Directory and account security:
>
> - Create and manage users.
> - Create and manage groups.
> - Manage account security by setting up basic 2SV or enhanced 2SV using security keys.
> - etc...

Comment: Seems like it is not free anymore but 6$/mo per user?

Comment: Cloud Identity free edition is free and supports 2FA. Here is the comparison page: https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7431902#zippy=%2Cdirectory%2Csecurity

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions here to make 2-Step Verification mandatory in G Suite:

1. If you will require 2-Step Verification of all users in the domain
   or within an existing organizational unit (OU), you may skip this
   step. If you need to have a different 2-Step Verification setting
   for a select group of users within an organization, create an
   admin-managed group containing all such users. See Use exception
   groups for detailed instructions on creating custom groups.
2. On the dashboard, click Reports, then select Security. Confirm that
   all users to be forced into 2-Step Verification are already enrolled
   in it, indicated by "Enrolled" in the 2-Step Verification Enrollment
   column.
3. On the dashboard, click Security > Basic settings > Enforce 2-Step
   Verification on users.
4. Select the organization where you wish to make 2-Step Verification
   mandatory. Then select Turn on enforcement. 2-Step Verification will
   become mandatory within 24 to 48 hours after turning on enforcement.
5. To have a suborganization inherit the 2-Step Verification setting
   from its parent organization, click the Use inherited button that
   appears near the right margin when you hover over the Authentication
   pane.
6. If you would like to exempt a group of users, select the group name
   (created in step 1) on the right-hand side keeping the organization
   selected on the left-hand side of the page and select Turn off
   enforcement. This will apply 2-Step Verification to all users in the
   selected organization except the users in the exception group.
7. Save your changes.

All users of the selected organization are now required to enter a secondary code from their mobile device.

Reference: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2548882?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Nagy Nick, this looks as if 2 factor can only be enforced with gsuite. Is that correct? 
I'd like to avoid GSuite because that would be EUR 4 per user per month (~EUR 5000 per year) just to enforce 2 factor.

Comment: The answer is well written and good step by step guide to get a solution for my original question. I'm therefore marking it as solved. 
Unfortunately nobody seems to care or know if 2fa can be enforced without gsuite on google. This is what the bounty was for and I'm not awarding it to this answer for this reason.